# React js with browserify and bootstrap raising error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I have created a Rails application and installed [react-rails](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails). I also installed [browserify-rails](https://github.com/browserify-rails/browserify-rails) to help me manage external react packages.

My whole setup seems to work well, but when I try to use the [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) package's modal component, I am presented with a firebug error which seems to block all other js from executing. The error reads:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a
>   ReactOwner can have refs....

I have tried numerous possible solutions, but no luck. I don't really understand why I'm getting the error and why it's only happening on specific components such as the `<Modal />`. If I use a normal html modal, there is no error. Here is my setup:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my_project",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^13.1.0",
    "browserify-incremental": "^3.1.1",
    "reactify": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.3.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.3",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.2"
  }
}
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require react
//= require react_ujs
//= require components
//= require_tree .

var React = window.React = global.React = require('react');
var ReactDOM= window.ReactDOM = global.ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
```

**application.rb**

```
...
config.browserify_rails.commandline_options = "-t reactify --extension=\".js.jsx\""
...
```

**components.js**

```
// Setup app into global name space for server rendering
var app = window.app = global.app = {};

var MyComponent = require('./components/my_component');
app.MyComponent = MyComponent;
```

**my_component.js.jsx**

```
var Modal = require('react-bootstrap').Modal;
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <Modal show={true}><h1>I'm working</h1></Modal>
    )
  }
});
module.exports = MyComponent;
```

I am extremely new to react and I'm thus not sure whether this error has something to do with my setup or if it's something else?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `<Element></Element>` this is called a higher order component. What you put between this tags does **not** show up as HTML - it is passed to the props of that component.

So this:

```
<Modal show={true}><h1>I'm working</h1></Modal>
```

Is passing an `h1` to `Modal` props. However looking at their documentation, you should be passing `Modal.X` properties to the `Modal` element. For example, from their docs:

```
       <Modal
          show={this.state.show}
          onHide={close}
          container={this}
          aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title"
        >
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title">Contained Modal</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            Elit est explicabo ipsum eaque dolorem blanditiis doloribus sed id ipsam, beatae, rem fuga id earum? Inventore et facilis obcaecati.
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button onClick={close}>Close</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @erik-sn. I copy and pasted your example into my component but unfortunately the error is still there.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue not long ago. This happened when I added a React component from npm. Multiple instances of React were being loaded on the page (one from `react-bootstrap` and one from my app).

Basically what I did was:

Added the `React` and `ReactDOM` globals in `application.js` (I see you already did this):

```
var React = window.React = global.React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = window.ReactDOM = global.ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
```

Removed the require react of asset pipeline:

```
//= require react
```

In my components, instead of using the global React, I've required them with browserify again:

```
var React = require('react');
var Modal = require('react-bootstrap').Modal;
var MyComponent = React.createClass({});
module.exports = MyComponent;
```

Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion @tegon. It does unfortunately not seem to fix the error.

Comment: That's odd, my setup is pretty similar to yours. @Herm sometimes I had problems with my local cache, have you tried running `rm -rf tmp/cache/browserify-rails/*`?